# ¿Por qué me devuelve undefined? TYPESCRIPT- Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, api, flask, servicio

Estoy aprendiendo angular por mi cuenta y a su vez TypeScript, y mi problema es el siguiente. Yo desde una ruta login de una API estoy retornando un Json con los datos de usuario incluido un Token. cuando imprimo los datos usando la variable "res" me muestra todos los datos en consola, pero cuando quiero acceder por ejemplo a "res.token" me devuelve "undefined".

```
  login(userData:User) : Observable<UserResponse | void>{
    return this.http.post<UserResponse>(`${environment.API_URL}login/`, userData).pipe(
      map((res:UserResponse) => {
        //this.saveToken(res.token);
        console.log(res)
        
        //saveToken();
      }),
      catchError( (err) => this.handlerError(err))
    );
  }
```

Este es el "interface" que tengo hecho:

```
export interface UserResponse {
    token: string;
    idRol: number;
    idUsers: number;
    nameUsers: string;
    passUsers: string;
}
```

Esto me devuelve la consola:

```
"
{"user: ": Array(1)}
"user: "
: 
Array(1)
0
: 
{idRol: 1, idUsers: 5, nameUsers: 'Admin', passUsers: '123', token: '68b4f32243964607f35d47e4c33471b'}
length
: 
1
[[Prototype]]
: 
Array(0)
[[Prototype]]
: 
Object
"
```

Esta es la ruta en la API (Por si acaso):

```
@cross_origin
@app.route("/login/", methods=['GET','POST']) # LOGIN ROUTE (OBVIOUS?)
def login():
    if request.method == 'POST': 
        nameUsers = request.json['nameUsers']
        passUsers = request.json['passUsers']
        #idRol = request.json['idRol']
        try:
            cursor = conn.connection.cursor()
            sql = "SELECT `idUsers`, `nameUsers`, `passUsers`, `users`.`idRol`, `token` FROM `users` INNER JOIN `rol` ON `users`.`idRol` = `rol`.`idRol` WHERE nameUsers='"+str(nameUsers)+"' and passUsers='"+str(passUsers)+"'"
            cursor.execute(sql)
            datos = cursor.fetchall()
            users=[]
            if datos:
                for fila in datos:
                    user = fila[1]
                    password = fila[2]
                    rol = fila[3]
                    token = fila[4]
                    user={
                        'idUsers':fila[0],
                        'nameUsers':fila[1],
                        'passUsers':fila[2],
                        'idRol':fila[3],
                        'token':fila[4]
                    }
                users.append(user)
                #session['username'] = user
                #session['password'] = password
                #session['idRol'] = rol
                #session['token'] = token
                print(str(rol)+" "+str(user)+" "+str(password))
                return jsonify({'user: ':users})
                #return jsonify({'MESSAGE':""+str(nameUsers)+" "+str(passUsers)})
            else:
                return jsonify({'MESSAGE':"USER NOT FOUND"})
            
        except Exception as ex:
            return jsonify({'Message':"Error: "+str(ex)})
    elif request.Method == 'GET':
        return jsonify({'MESSAGE':"GET <-- this is the method"})
```

Comment: Ya verificaste que en la respuesta del servidor venga el token?

Comment: Añade lo que te muestra ese `console.log(res)`. Por otro lado, decir: _los pretendo guardar en un "interface"_, no es correcto. Una Interface es como un molde, estructura o contrato. Realmente lo que estás haciendo es indicar a Typescript que los datos recibidos tienen la estructura declarada en la interface, de esta forma, en tiempo de desarrollo, puedes acceder de forma "segura" a los elementos definidos en la estructura de datos (interface). Saludos

Comment: @GerardoFlores efectivamente, el token viene en la respuesta, el token y todos los datos del usuario.

Comment: @MauricioContreras ya lo corregí, y por si llega a ser necesario, coloqué la ruta de la API.

Comment: Parece que el JSON que estás recibiendo de tu API tiene una estructura diferente a la que esperas. Si te fijas, el JSON que recibes tiene una clave llamada "user: " (nota los dos puntos y el espacio), y el valor de esta clave es un arreglo de objetos de usuario.

Comment: Resulta que la respuesta es un Array y no un Objeto, por ello cuando accedes a la propiedad `token` te dice `undefined`, porque `token` no es una propiedad de Array. Podrías acceder al valor en la posición 0 así: `console.log(res[0].token)`. Y en todo caso, el tipo de dato devuelto (usando el _interface_) sería: `res: UserResponse[]` o bien `res: Array<UserResponse>`. Prueba eso y comenta el resultado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando intentas acceder a res.token, estás buscando una propiedad llamada "token" en el objeto "res", pero esa propiedad no existe. En su lugar, debes acceder al primer elemento del arreglo y luego a la propiedad "token". Algo así:

```
console.log(res["user: "][0].token);
```

Si quieres acceder a los demás datos del usuario, también debes hacerlo de esta manera:

```
let idRol = res["user: "][0].idRol;
let idUsers = res["user: "][0].idUsers;
let nameUsers = res["user: "][0].nameUsers;
let passUsers = res["user: "][0].passUsers;
```

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver tu problema. cualquier cosa me avisas.

aparte de lo otro que te comente con "user: " ...

Comment: Hola!! Muchísimas gracias por ayudarme... cambié el console.log() por este "console.log(res[0].token)" pero me arroja un error "Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '"User: "' can't be used to index type 'UserResponse'.
  Property 'User: ' does not exist on type 'UserResponse'.". Estoy intentando entender la respuesta, soy muy nuevo con este framework

Comment: el problema como te decia es por que estas usando en tu json esto: `"User: "`

Comment: cambié el tipo a "res" por any pero me arroja "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'token')" dejé el mismo log, "console.log(res[0].token)"

Comment: amigo muchísimas gracias ya pude acceder a los datos!

Answer (score 0):

muchísimas gracias por su ayuda, pude acceder a los datos del arreglo y el método en el servicio quedó de la siguiente manera:

```
  login(userData:User) : Observable<void>{
    return this.http.post<UserResponse>(`${environment.API_URL}login/`, userData).pipe(
      map((res:any) => {
        console.log(res["User"][0].token);
        
        //saveToken();
      }),
      catchError( (err) => this.handlerError(err))
    );
  }
```